# Bendy bone ends don't follow rig, also 'stretch to' issues

Tags: rigging

So I have a little bunny that I need to animate for a school final, although when I connect the bendy bones together the ends which I would use to control the bones don't follow the root bone

Also when using the 'stretch to' constraint to allow the flexibility of the bones, by themselves it works fine, but when I joined them to the rest of the armature they squish up against the main bone

[image]
Screenshot showing squish issues

[image]
End points stay in place while rest moves sporadically

Any help would be immensly appreciated  >.<

Comment: please, don't paste, as suggested, on pasteall! use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then add the provided link in the question

Comment: Thanks, I would include the link in the question but I can't post any more links, so here it is

Comment: https://puu.sh/xCBk5/9233278e56.blend

Comment: then post the link BSE here, I'll add it to the question...

Comment: I attempted to upload but the max size is 30 mb and my file is 80mb, so I used puush. Is there any way to upload larger file sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well i think i see what goes wrong, its the automatic weight ctrl p that goes wrong, essentially each part of the bear is a disconnected mesh. 
If you want it to behave like that, when arms and legs are connected as a real bear (where those can be loose parts, connected by a single pont) then with automatic-weight paint you have to select the individual mesh and then the individual bone and do weight paint. (but first split your mesh by those lose moving parts).

Another bear way, would be as if those parts did not have a single joint point but are sticked with needle and rope, around another body part, and so its more like 1 volumes object (a single part stuffed bear), instead of amultiple loose objects (a multiple stuffed parts bear). In that case your mesh has to be like that too. This is the most easy form to rig, since that wont require to do automatic weight paint to each single bone but all bones can be automated-weightpaint all-together. As one single operation.

Currently the automatic weight paint sees an object that exist out of multiple objects whose mesh is not like the seccond bear (one volumes object) and it gets confused from a multiple volumes object.

- i actually had wondered for a while if multiple parts based objects (like multi stuffed bears) where possible so far i never rigged them. But thanks to your question i see that it works but it requires more additional handling since then you have to select the individual bone that belongs to it.

  - I think i prefer the single mesh rigs though, easier todo

Comment: Thank you! now the rig works like the way it did when it was all separate. You were right with the weight painting I hadn't set it up correctly, now the mesh moves as one unit when moving the root bone and stretches and bends with the arms and legs. The strange movement was from multiple bones having small influences on the same bit of mesh, but for this character that wasn't necessary. I also had to parent the end bones to the root to keep it from staying in place. Thanks for the reply! ^.^

Comment: Did you eventually go for the "single stuffed mesh" or for multiple stuffed meshes, ea combined objects that form 1 bear ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Yeah I chose to combine it all together, it would make it easier to select the mesh as a whole while animating

Answer (score 0):

You might add your blend file to see whats wrong: http://pasteall.org/blend/
I assume that you didnt apply scale to the model before doing automic weights (that could explain the weird lower picture). Make sure you parent the bones correctly. If you find it difficult to make a skeleton start with rigify and remove the bones you dont need, then in the end turn some of the bones in bendy bones.

Comment: pasteall.org is not the best site to upload files, links on that site expire after a few months. To upload files for the questions and answers on this site is preferable to use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I attempted to upload through giant cow films but it wouldn't let me since the max upload size is 30mb and my file is 80mb. The file is available through puush